# Typo3 Magic Image resizing

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a problem,

in my RTE I resize images to a certain size, but after saving, they are reset to either width or height of 300. Smaller sizes are kept, only bigger ones are limited.

I know that there exists a maximum size, after some googleing, i found the following:

```
RTE.default.buttons.image.options.magic.maxWidth = 1000
RTE.default.buttons.image.options.magic.maxHeight= 1000
RTE.default.buttons.image.options.plain.maxWidth = 1000
RTE.default.buttons.image.options.plain.maxHeight= 1000
```

But also after inserting it to the PageTS, the images are limited to 300px.

Could someone with more Typo3 experience please help me?

Typo3 version is 6.1.7

Answer (score 3):

I used tx_news and it was impossible to get images larger than 300px width.
I did  `RTE.default.buttons.image.options.magic.maxWidth = 1000` and `styles.content.imgtext.maxWInText = 1000`.

The problem is the `setMagicImageMaximumDimensions` in `MagicImageService` looks only for `RTE.buttons.image.options.magic.maxWidth` (no **default**).

So I have to use,

```
RTE.buttons.image.options.magic.maxWidth = 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

There are more [constants](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/css_styled_content/latest/Configuration/Constants/Index.html#constants-styles-content-imgtext) to define the maximal width of images:

Usage:

```
styles.content.imgtext {
    maxW = XXX
    maxWInText = YYY
}
```

You can also manipulate these widths using registers, which is very helpful to set these values to different values per column. The registers are called `maxImageWidth` and `maxImageWidthInText` respectively.